# Apache storm-jdbc maven integration

Tags: maven, hadoop, jdbc, github, apache-storm

How to import the dependency for storm-jdbc in maven pom.xml

https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-jdbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way i got the git and compiled the jar files and installed them in my maven repo using maven install:install-file goal in my eclipse and this worked for me.